# Adding progress bar to calculation

Tags: c++, user-interface, design-patterns

I have a class that does a complex calculation which may take a long time. I'd like to add a progress bar with Abort button. However, I would like to avoid mixing calculation code with GUI code if possible.

Are there any good design patterns for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant design pattern is the [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern: your class doing a calculation is the "subject", it maintains a list of Observers, implementing a common Observer interface, and when its state changes (i.e. the amount of progress has changed), it notifies each observer via an update() call.

Comment: So basically signals and slots. Shame on me for not realizing this. Thanks :-)